# @JsonFilter set default setFailOnUnknownId(true)

Tags: jackson

is there anyway to make @JsonFilter be ignored if there's no filter configured for them automatically?

`Could not write content: Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'xx'; no FilterProvider configured`

It's quite a pain as I added `@JsonFilter` for one object which was used by multiple projects and I have to make changes for the other projects too